# AS3 Problems with MovieClips manipulation

Tags: actionscript-3, root, movieclip

I'm trying to set a dynamic text called text_amount  inside a movieclip called PiattoBalance  in the stage from another movieclip called Bet1 in the same stage but i'm getting error 1120: undefined property PiattoBalance.

here is the code inside the Bet1 MovieClip:

```
stop();
visible = false;
MovieClip(root).PiattoBalance.text_amount.text = String(int(PiattoBalance.text_amount.text) + int(text_bet.text));
```

What's wrong?

Comment: error 1120: undefined property PiattoBalance. Please do a trace(PiattoBalance) see the output

Comment: compilator error, it doesn't even start..

Answer (score 0):

```
MovieClip(root)
```

Why would you use "root", please don't use "root" use stage, or the container which contains your movieclip. "Rooting" died in AS2.0, bad habit to keep it.

You could check whether the PiattoBalance object exists or not.

```
if(MovieClip(root).PiattoBalance != null)
    MovieClip(root).PiattoBalance.text_amount.text = String(int(PiattoBalance.text_amount.text) + int(text_bet.text));
```

If exists, then check the "PiattoBalance.text_amount".

Comment: using 
stage.PiattoBalance.text_amount.text = String(int(PiattoBalance.text_amount.text) 
+ int(text_bet.text));
gives me the same error specifying that comes from stage...

Comment: Then your PiattoBalance textbox doesn't exist when you call the code.

Comment: but how? they are automatically created when you enter the frame, because are objects on the stage.

Comment: Please give more information about where is the code, and when do you run it. Can't help if you don't give enough AND proper, precise information.

Comment: on the stage there are 2 symbols: PiattoBalance and Bet1
Inside PiattoBalance there is a dynamic textfield text_amount.
Adding an animation to Bet1 in frame 30 i wrote the code of the question to modify PiattoBalance >>> text_amount

Comment: Isn't your "text_bet" text inside yout "Bet1" movieclip? If so, then it should be "int(Bet1.text_bet.text)"

Comment: No because the code is inside Bet1 movieclip... the problem is that even if I trace PiattoBalance, it looks like still undefined... but it's on the stage! :/

Comment: So the code is inside the Bet1 movieclip, then try MovieClip(parent) instead of MovieClip(root).